# TensorRT context.enqueue gives wrong result for all frames other than first

Tags: c++, nvidia, tensorrt

I am trying to run inference on multiple images using TensorRT API.
Pseudo Code snippet for my application is

```
context.enqueue(batchSize, buffers, stream, nullptr);
```

Here,

```
buffers[0] = batchSize * INPUT_C * INPUT_H * INPUT_W
        buffers[1] = batchSize * outputSize
```

If I run with batchSize=1 , I get correct output but with batchSize > 1 , detection for images other than first image are wrong.
Further, with batchSize=1, inference time is 7ms and for batchSize=3 it is around 16ms. So solving this issue will give a lot of boost to my application and as in general.

Can someone please suggest me what all things I can try to solve this issue.
I am allocating memory to "buffers" this way

```
for (int b = 0; b < engine.getNbBindings(); b++)
    {
        DimsCHW dims = static_cast<DimsCHW&&>(engine.getBindingDimensions(b));
        size_t size = batchSize * dims.c() * dims.h() * dims.w() * sizeof(float);
        std::cout << "size of buff = " << size << std::endl;
        CudaCHECK(cudaMalloc(&buffers[b], size));
    }
```

Is it supposed to be a 1D vector or 2D vector?.
Thanks!

Comment: "Is it supposed to be a 1D vector or 2D vector?" - what is "it" ? Note that memory is 1D. NVidia generally uses tensor descriptors to describe how an 1D chunk of memory is to be interpreted.

Comment: I was asking about the variable "buffers". But I think in general answered my question with the statement "NVidia generally uses tensor descriptors to describe how an 1D chunk of memory is to be interpreted".

Comment: @MSalters BTW do you have any experience working with multiple images inference with TensorRT API?. Were you able to make it work?.What  performance gain did you get?.

Comment: Sorry, I was recently looking into TensorRT but stumbled across this question in the C++ stream; never actually wrote TensorRT code. My company does audio, not images, so we need to figure out how these NVidia tensors really work. We can't just use image examples, we have to rewrite them all.